# React Axios: How to send just the state value of my prop to backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, react-props

So, I've passed my parent state to my child component as a prop called title. I want to make a put request with axios using the value of that prop. If I render it in a div it returns the state value but when I put it into the axios parameters, it doesn't. Instead, in my console log, it shows a prop object:

```
{$$typeof: Symbol(react.element), key: null, ref: null, props: {…}, type: ƒ, …}
$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
type: class Title
key: null
ref: null
props: {title: "Godfather"}
_owner: null
_store: {validated: false}
_self: componentData {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, state: {…}, …}
_source: {fileName: "C:\Users\Craig\Desktop\project - Copy\client\src\components\Movies\SendingMovie.js", lineNumber: 20}
__proto__: Object
```

Basically, I just want to send `'Godfather'`. Not an entire object thing like above. 
Also when I create a dummy state for this child component and give it `movie: 'Godfather'` and then
pass it into the axios put request, the database registers and it works. So my back-end code is fine but
I'm not sure why props isn't giving me just the state value.

Shortened Code Snippet:

Parent (component called Foods):

```
class Votes extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
   this.state = {
   error: null,
   isLoaded: false,
   foods: [],
   activefood:'', //new added
};

...

render() {
     const title = this.state.activefood
     return(
     <p>
      title={title}
     </p>
)
}
```

Child:

```
import React, {
    Fragment,
    useState,
    useEffect,
    Component
} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Votes from './Foods';
import Title from './Title';


export default class SendingFood extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        error: null,
        clicked: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick() {
    this.setState({
        clicked: true,
    });
}


   patchFunction() {
     this.setState({isLoading: true});
    axios.patch('api/food/modify', {foodname: <Title title={this.props.title}/>})
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
            this.setState({
                 isLoading: false,
            })
           console.log('sent');
      },
              (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error

          });

        }
      )
    };


   combinedFunction() {
    this.patchFunction();
    this.handleClick();
}

 render(){
   const {isLoading, error} = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div style={{color: "red"}}>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    };
 return (
    <Fragment>
      <Title title={this.props.title}/>
   <button className="primary" onClick={() => {  this.patchFunction() }}>Submit Vote</button>

     </Fragment>
          )}
  }
```

---

```
import React, {
    Fragment,
    useState,
    useEffect,
    Component
} from "react";

    export default class Title extends React.Component{
        render() {
            return (
                <Fragment>
                {this.props.title}
                </Fragment>
            );
        }
    }
```

Up until this point, I've been using react to render props and pass data and state to other components but I'm stuck now where I want a child component to receive state data and send it to the back end. Maybe i'm using the wrong procedure or wrong tools for the job?

Comment: Have you looked at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43573297/put-request-with-simple-string-as-request-body

Comment: My prop is being called from my parent where the onlick gives a state change, dynamic in essence. I capture that and pass it to my child. YOU have just referenced a question where someone was getting a req.body error. I am getting no errors. please read the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a snippet of the code of how are you passing the state of the parent to the child ?