# Axios is sending the wrong token

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, local-storage, asyncstorage

In React, this is working:

```
let token = localStorage.getItem("token");

axios
      .post(
        `http://localhost/api`,
        (data: data),
        {
          crossdomain: true,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
          },
        }
      )
```

Everything is ok. It gives success.

But in React Native (AsyncStorage), it gives wrong token error (403):

```
let token = AsyncStorage.getItem("token");

    axios
          .post(
            `http://localhost/api`,
            (data: data),
            {
              crossdomain: true,
            },
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type, Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
              },
            }
          )
```

In console.log(token), everything seems great. I can see my token. It also works well in Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/api#getitem):

> Returns:
>
> `Promise` resolving with a string value, if entry exists for given `key`,
> or `null` otherwise.
>
> `Promise` can also be rejected in case of underlying storage error.

Since it returns a `Promise`, you should get the token using `.then()` or `async/await`:

```
async function doRequest() {
  let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
  // do request
}
```

Comment: Your code is okay, now I am getting the token but axios is not working again. Is there a problem with the data types? Or does the expo fail? @Rafael

Comment: Does it throw an error? Could you try `axios.post('http://localhost/api', data,  { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+ token } });` and check if it works ? I removed the back ticks just because of code formatting here

Comment: Hi @Rafael, this code doesn't work either. It just throws `Request failed with status code 403`

Comment: @NightFighter Are you sure you are sending the body data (`data`) correctly? As you posted in your question, `(data: data)` won't work, but as I did in the comment should work if it is in the correct format. Can you check what you are receiving in the server?

Comment: My body's data type is string. Is this data type correct or should I change it? Server gives `"POST /api HTTP/1.1" 403 42 "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"`. Also with Postman, it is working.

Comment: If your server expects a string, try adding to axios header `"Content-Type": "text/plain"`. It should look like `{ headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer '+ token, "Content-Type": "text/plain" } }`. Maybe you will need to send body data as `'\"' + data + '\"'`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43573297/8839059)

Answer (score 0):

I want to know whoever sees this post in the future that Axios did not send my headers in React-Native. In such a case, maybe you should try fetch.

@Rafael's answer was also great.

```
fetch("http://localhost/api", {
      method: "post",
      headers: new Headers({
        "x-auth-token": `${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }),
      body: {
        body
      },
    });
```